# Simple examples of simplicial complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I wanted to think about the most basic examples of simplicial complexes and here are what I could think of.

Let $V= \{p\}$ a single point. Then $K=(V, S)$, where $S=\{p\}$, is this the simplest example of simplicial complexes?

Comment: Yes. But the question is vague, what is the measure of being "simple"?

Comment: I suppose the simplest example of a simplicial complex is the empty set.